# Small symbol next to section headers

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am writing a school report which has to be evaluated by two different teachers.

I need to mark which sections each teacher should read. I guess I can make a small symbol next to the header to mark which teacher the specific section is written to.

How is this possible?

I guess I can do something like

```
\section{Milking the Cow}
\teacher{A}
Some text
```

or editing the section headers or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A margin symbol could be clearer and less intrusive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\def\Smith{\rlap{\protect\makebox[-3cm]{\color{red}\S}}}
\def\Philips{\rlap{\protect\makebox[-3cm]{\color{red}$\Phi$}}}
\def\Omar{\rlap{\protect\makebox[-3cm]{\color{red}$\Omega$}}}
\begin{document}
\section{\Smith Lore ipsum}\lipsum[2]
\section{\Philips Nulla malesuada}\lipsum[3]
\section{\Omar Quisque ullamcorper}\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 7):

Give them some magic so that they can give you good marks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\TA{{\color{red}\staveVI}} \def\TB{{\color{blue}\staveXXXVI}}
\usepackage{staves,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\TA\lipsum[1]
\section {test}
\TB\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the definitions to robust commands you can also put them in the section title.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\TA{{\color{red}\staveVI}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\TB{{\color{blue}\staveXXXVI}}
```

[image]

I sort of like them so as `cleaders`

```
\makeatletter
\def\TA{%
   \bgroup%
   \leavevmode
   \color{red}\tiny%
   \cleaders \hb@xt@ 1.5em{\hss\staveVI\hss}\hfill
   \kern\z@
   \egroup}

\def\TB{%
   \bgroup%
   \leavevmode
   \color{blue}\tiny%
   \cleaders \hb@xt@ 1.5em{\hss\staveXXXVI\hss}\hfill
   \kern\z@
   \egroup}  
 \makeatother
```

Leader glue is one of those magical ingedients of `TeX`!

[image]

Comment: Haha - I like it. Can the symbols be right aligned in the section header and with the same height as the text, so it wont "conflict" with the normal layout. Thank you!

Comment: @Jamgreen This will need some more magic. Change to `\DeclareRobustCommand\TA{\hfill\scalebox{.3}{\mbox{\color{red}\staveVI}}}`, but when they are smaller they lose their power:) Also don't forget to add `\usepackage{graphicx}` for the scalebox

Comment: Now the problem is that they are also present in the table of contents. Is it possible to hide them there? :-D